# Correctly merge Landsat images in a median mosaic using different tiles

Tags: python, gdal, merge, rasterio, landsat

I have several Landsat 8 and 9 images, from two different tiles that I want to merge together in a median mosaic. The tiles are tiles that overlap, with two images for each tile.

What I'm doing to merge them in a median mosaic is this:

```py
def get_median_img(imgs, no_of_bands):
    bands_medians = []
    for b in range(no_of_bands):
        bands = [img.sel(band=b + 1) for img in imgs]
        bands_comp = xr.concat(bands, dim='band')
        #compute the median ignoring NaN values
        bands_medians.append(xr.DataArray(np.nanmedian(bands_comp, axis=0), dims=['y', 'x'], coords={'y': bands_comp.y, 'x': bands_comp.x}))
    return xr.concat(bands_medians, dim='band')
```

where the parameter *imgs* comes from here:
`tci_images.append(rioxarray.open_rasterio(image, chunks={'x': 1000, 'y': 1000}))`

Considering we are working with different tiles I understand that the profile of each image is different.
I'm trying to save the median composite but I'm not sure what parameters I should give to the profile.
At this moment I'm using the `merge` method from *rasterio* to merge the images together and get the *out_transform* which is the **affine** information `mosaic, out_transform = merge(images)`. I then copy the profile from one of the images in the `output_meta`.
After this I update the profile

```py
    output_meta.update(
        {"driver": "GTiff",
            "height": mosaic.shape[1],
            "width": mosaic.shape[2],
            "transform": out_transform,
        }
    )
```

And save the raster using the rasterio:

```py
    with rasterio.Env():
        with rasterio.open(median_path_name, 'w', **output_meta) as dst:
            dst.write(median_image.astype(rasterio.float32))
```

However, the output is the median mosaic with the wrong georeferencing, and I cannot seem to put it correctly.

These are two images from different tiles:
[image][image]

The expected result should be this:
[image: expected_resilt]

However this is the output. Which seems to be mirrored:
[image: output]

See? The *blue* image is what I want, but the code I'm running results in the *green* image.
[image]

I printed the shape and profile for each image in case that helps. Any suggestion on a easier way to do this?

```
(7841, 7721) shape of masked.tif
{'driver': 'GTiff', 'dtype': 'float32', 'nodata': None, 'width': 7721, 'height': 7841, 'count': 7, 'crs': CRS.from_epsg(32629), 'transform': Affine(30.0, 0.0, 432585.0,
       0.0, -30.0, 4581915.0), 'blockysize': 1, 'tiled': False, 'interleave': 'pixel'} profile of masked.tif
(7821, 7711) shape of masked.tif
{'driver': 'GTiff', 'dtype': 'float32', 'nodata': None, 'width': 7711, 'height': 7821, 'count': 7, 'crs': CRS.from_epsg(32629), 'transform': Affine(30.0, 0.0, 469785.0,
       0.0, -30.0, 4740315.0), 'blockysize': 1, 'tiled': False, 'interleave': 'pixel'} profile of masked.tif
(7821, 7701) shape of masked.tif
{'driver': 'GTiff', 'dtype': 'float32', 'nodata': None, 'width': 7701, 'height': 7821, 'count': 7, 'crs': CRS.from_epsg(32629), 'transform': Affine(30.0, 0.0, 464085.0,
       0.0, -30.0, 4740315.0), 'blockysize': 1, 'tiled': False, 'interleave': 'pixel'} profile of masked.tif
(7831, 7711) shape of masked.tif
{'driver': 'GTiff', 'dtype': 'float32', 'nodata': None, 'width': 7711, 'height': 7831, 'count': 7, 'crs': CRS.from_epsg(32629), 'transform': Affine(30.0, 0.0, 470385.0,
       0.0, -30.0, 4740615.0), 'blockysize': 1, 'tiled': False, 'interleave': 'pixel'} profile of masked.tif
(7831, 7701) shape of masked.tif
{'driver': 'GTiff', 'dtype': 'float32', 'nodata': None, 'width': 7701, 'height': 7831, 'count': 7, 'crs': CRS.from_epsg(32629), 'transform': Affine(30.0, 0.0, 470385.0,
       0.0, -30.0, 4740615.0), 'blockysize': 1, 'tiled': False, 'interleave': 'pixel'} profile of masked.tif
```

Comment: For mosaicking xarray datasets/dataarrays, I use merge module from rioxarray. Try it: [merge module](https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/rioxarray.html#rioxarray-merge-module)

Comment: @aldo_tapia will try it. i was reading the documentation and found no median method for the merge. is that true? which method do you normally use?

Comment: Is median the appropriate method? Since you are merging two images, is ok to compute the median for two values? The module I sent you uses first, last, min, max or a custom function, so you can create a UDF for computing the median if you still want

Comment: @aldo_tapia I want to create a mosaic with several images, so  that is why I want to use the median, because it is always more than just to values. I'll check that custom function then.

Comment: Then the procedure should be: 1) mosaic scenes by date. 2) stack scenes by time dimension. 3) reduce time dimension using median